# heroku and domain name conventions

Tags: heroku, dns

(tried on Server fault, so going to try here)

Hi I recently setup my octopress blog at http://davidmjohnson.me. This domain works fine, but when I try http://www.davidmjohnson.me I get a "heroku no app found." Why is the www not working. Would really appreciate an explanation. I bought my domain name at dnsimple. Do I need to add a redirect from "http://www.dav..." to just "http://dav..." ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to configure this domain (and any subdomain) in the heroku CLI application (equiv. of ssh-ing into the machine and changing the nginx/apache location/virtualhost configuration).

I see they have an entry about this in their reference:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

To elaborate a bit [from the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#subdomains-wwwmydomaincom):

> Subdomains ( www.mydomain.com)
>
> For each subdomain you want to setup configure your DNS provider using
>   a CNAME record pointing the subdomain to the applicable Heroku
>   hostname.
>
> If the app is on Cedar, then CNAME the subdomain to myapp.herokuapp.com
>   If Bamboo, then myapp.heroku.com
>
> **In DNSimple** a CNAME
>   record entry for a Cedar app would look like:
>   [image]
>
> You can confirm that your DNS is configured correctly with the host
>   command:
>   $ host www.example.com
>
> www.example.com is an alias for myapp.herokuapp.com.
>
> myapp.herokuapp.com is an alias for ar.herokuapp.com.
>
> ar.herokuapp.com is an alias for argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
>
> argon-stack-1879049447.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.20.157.144
>
> ...

Comment: That would simply be setting up a wildcard subdomain at his registrar to: *.davidmjohnson.me CNAME pointing at his Heroku app. He still should set up the correct naked domain forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should really be the other way around. It is much better practice to point CNAMEs at Heroku apps, since Heroku apps have no real "static" IP. Since naked domains need an A-record, pointing a naked domain to a Heroku app makes everything much less stable. So the best practice is to forward your naked domain to a "www" subdomain, and then point the "www" CNAME to your Heroku app.

Heroku goes into detail about this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).